# Get part of digit in separate variables

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all, substr

I have number 14969126 and want to separate like

```
$last_five_digits = 69126;
$rest_of_digits = 149;
```

I have tried

```
$last_five_digits = substr($postalcode, -5);
```

But how can i get rest of the digits.

Please provide any suggestion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$firstDigits = substr($postalcode, 0, -5);
//=> 149
```

Answer (score 2):

`preg_split()` returns an array:

```
list($first, $last_five) =
    preg_split('/(\d{5})$/', '14969126', null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$postalcode = 14969126;

 $last_five_digits = substr($postalcode, -5);
 $rest_of_digits = substr($postalcode,0,3);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.